# Ubuntu Updates: How Scared Should I Be?

Tags: 14.04, updates

I had an install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a different machine, with Nvidia drivers manually installed. I "accepted" an automatic update and it hosed my computer, I still haven't been able to get it back working.

But no worries, I installed 14.04 on a different machine and it's (currently) working fine. But 48 hours after the install I get an auto update notice. How worried should I be? The first laptop was a 2010 build, the latest one is a 2013 build. If that matters.

Comment: Your problem with the first install is that if you manually install the nvidia driver, you need to re-install it with every kernel upgrade. The "solution" is to install the drivers using the driver in the ubuntu repository. Your "problem" has nothing to to with ubuntu packages. Upgrades are generally safe, but if you run into a problem, post back. Otherwise it is hard to predict problems / solutions in advance.

Comment: The solution is to install dkms before manually installing the driver. Then, when the kernel updates, all of the manually installed kernel modules that use dkms will be automatically updated to the new kernel using the dkms directories. `sudo apt-get install dkms`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be that worried if you have not installed the nvidia driver on the newer computer in the same way that you did on the first one. There are a few things you should be aware of.

First:

the nvidia drivers will use dkms if it is installed when you manually install the driver. Before installing the nvidia driver, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Then, you may install or reinstall the nvidia driver and should not have any issues updating to new kernels and will not have to reinstall the drivers after updating kernels.

Next:

you should be able to log in from grub using the old kernel. Select "Advanced Options" and then select the older kernel from the next menu. This will give you a way to use the machine until you install dkms and reinstall the driver (on the older computer).

Finally:

You can manually apply updates on any machine using the command-line and doing so will offer two options. Run the following commands in an open terminal.

Option one:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Using the above option is safe and should not perform any updates that will break the system. This way, you can perform security updates and other bug fixes without disrupting the system. This is for when you are working on a project or using the machine for production and need to maintain function.

Option two:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This option will perform all updates including kernel upgrades and other updates that  make changes to the system and could affect the overall function. Use this when you are not in the middle of a project and have some time to fix any problems that may arise. Problems are not likely but are possible as you have found out. Also, problems are not typical. Installing dkms before manually installing nvidia should prevent future issues.